# Apt Update Error in Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS** version. Somehow from today morning I'm receiving the below traceback while running **apt update** command

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for testuser: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitseater/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Fetched 114 kB in 2s (73.9 kB/s)                         
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 27, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 95, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 141, in _fill_commands
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=sub.returncode, 
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/lib/apt/apt-helper cat-file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_cnf_Commands-amd64' returned non-zero exit status 100.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Please let me know what is the issue here

Comment: Input/output error: could be a failing hard drive.

Comment: Thank @vanadium. But all other commands are running such as install, uninstall. autoremove

Comment: What happens if you disable at least the bitseater repository, or any other PPA you added?

Comment: Have you done anything to your system's python configuration?

Comment: @vanadium When I disable a ppa, the same issue is occurring. I had installed python3.8 using https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Add that information to your question - use edit. It is actually the first likely reason why your system has broken. You should never update the python version that comes with the system: the entire desktop depends on it, and there is no guatantee that everything will continue to work on a different python version. Advise: restore the original python version first (however might be difficult because the APT system is broken).